# Using Electrum, a Bitcoin wallet, generated ZPUB extended public key for Ethereum purposes?

Tags: ether, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, bitcoin, public-key

I would like to set up a watch-only wallet, in which I could have Ethereum coins along with my Bitcoins.
I have already generated an extended public key of type ZPUB using Bitcoin-only Electrum wallet.
Would it be somehow possible to reuse this ZPUB extended public key to create my Ethereum wallet too?
And is there any wallet that would allow me to receive and watch both, Ethereum and Bitcoins and to also spend them if I decide to import the seed phrase.

PS: I'm total noob here.

Thanks!